# Error: Relation "abc.emp_audit" does not exist. when i add schema name in all objects. it was working fine without schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

```
 CREATE TABLE abc.emp
         (
                      empname TEXT NOT NULL,
                      salary INTEGER
         );

 CREATE TABLE abc.emp_audit
         (
                      operation CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                      stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                      userid TEXT NOT NULL,
                      empname TEXT NOT NULL,
                      salary INTEGER
         );

      CREATE FUNCTION abc.audit()
     returns TRIGGER AS $$ ...
    EXECUTE format
   ( 'INSERT INTO %I SELECT ''I'', current_timestamp, %L, ($1::%I.%I).*', 
   tg_argv[0], CURRENT_USER, tg_table_schema, tg_table_name ) using new;
  ... $$;

 CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit_trig after
 INSERT
 OR
UPDATE
OR
DELETE
ON abc.emp FOR each row
EXECUTE FUNCTION
abc.audit('abc.emp_audit');
```

I got error : Relation "abc.emp_audit" does not exist . How to correct this issue when schema added in tables ad audit tables, functions, and triggers arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use two parameters, one for the schema and one for the table. In the trigger function, use

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      'INSERT INTO %I.%I SELECT ''I'', current_timestamp, %L, ($1::%I.%I).*', 
      TG_ARGV[0], TG_ARGV[1],
      current_user,
      TG_TABLE SCHEMA, TG_TABLE NAME
   ) USING NEW;
```

Then define the trigger as

```
CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE FUNCTION abc.audit('abc', 'emp_audit');
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the one proposed by @Laurenz Albe is to stick to a single parameter and then split it before creating the `INSERT` statement, e.g

```
CREATE FUNCTION abc.audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
DECLARE 
  tbname TEXT := (string_to_array(tg_argv[0],'.'))[1];
  schname TEXT := (string_to_array(tg_argv[0],'.'))[2];
BEGIN
-- rest of your code ...
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I SELECT ''I'', current_timestamp, %L, ($1::%I.%I).*',
         tbname,schname,CURRENT_USER,tg_table_schema,tg_table_name ) USING NEW;
-- rest of your code ...
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit_trig AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON abc.emp FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION abc.audit('abc.emp_audit');
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2c18e8d642f66369b8d99421ae10b20)